# Trying to implement an Ajax function rails 3 .load()

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

This is my first time trying to implement an Ajax call in rails 3, though I am using the .load function ( I still hope this is Ajax otherwise im understanding this incorrectly)

So i have a search form that returns results via a get request which renders on a different page, i would like the results to appear on the same page as the search form

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => 'search', :action => 'search'}, {:method => 'get'})  do |select| %>
<%= label_tag :search, "Enter Keywords Here" %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
 (I have shortened the form)
<%= submit_tag "Search", :class => "searchbutton" %>
<% end %>
```

Jquery/Ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.searchbutton').click(function() {
$('#searchres').load('shared/searchresults');

});

});
```

View

```
<h3>Search Recipes here</h3>
  <%= render 'shared/searchrecipes' %>
    <div id ="searchres">
</div>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: you miss a `;` above last `});` and what is your error?

Comment: thanks for that, still doesnt solve issue though :(

Comment: the search results still render on a separate page

Comment: `$(document)`, not `$('document')`

Comment: full of simple errors tonight I am, still not working though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to this being an AJAX call, you need to add `remote: true` besides `method: :get`, getting an html parameter hash like this:

```
{:method => 'get', :remote => true}
```

When Rails finda remote call, it prevents the default automagically. Otherwise, you would need to modify you javascript like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.searchbutton').click(function(evt) {
    $('#searchres').load('shared/searchresults');
    evt.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: excellent, now i understand, thank you so much, working now :)